# How to place all the delimited records in one column in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk, sh

I have one file abc.txt which contains :

```
abc,byc
ccf
gyh
```

I want to place all the records (which are comma separated) in one line.

```
abc
byc
ccf
gyh
```

Please help

Answer (score 6):

With `tr`:

```
tr ',' '\n' < abc.txt
```

This replaces each comma with a newline.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` version:

```
awk '{sub(/,/,RS)}1' file
abc
byc
ccf
gyh
```

A `gnu awk` version

```
awk -v RS="\n|," '{$1=$1}1' file
abc
byc
ccf
gyh
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/,/\n/' file
```